# Do you need to proof this statement? "If a function has a minimum and maximum, it's not monotone"?

Tags: functions, derivatives, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I'm supposed to proof monotony. I have calculated the extremums first and realized that the function has a minimum and a maximum.

Is this enough to claim that the function isn't monotone because it has a minimum and a maximum? Or is a proof required to prove this statement?

This would safe me a lot time in the exam if you can just write that.

Let's take tasks like that:

"Proof if the function is monotone" or "Is the function monotone in $\mathbb{R}?$"

What do you think?

Comment: It depends. If your function is only defined on an interval $[a,b]$ for example, this is not necessarily true.

Comment: $\sin x$ *is* monotone on $x \in [0, \pi /2]$. You'll need to state it more carefully.

Comment: @angryavian So if it's mentioned to proof in $\mathbb{R}$ as example, I can use it? Or if it's just asked "Is the function monotone?"?

Comment: @cnmesr Still not necessarily. Constant functions are monotone and have a minimum and maximum. A less trivial example would be some function that is $0$ on $(-\infty,0]$, increases to $1$ linearly on $[0,1]$, and then is constant $1$ on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @cnmesr What do you think of $y=x$?

Comment: If we add enough hypotheses, the statement will become true.  However, one couldn't just state it as "common knowledge" without proof on an exam and expect good results.

Comment: If it's not strictly monotone or not an an interval, no, because it needn't be true.  If it has a max at x it should be trivial to show there is an x_1 < x < x_2 where f(x_1) < f(x) and f(x) > f(x_2).

Comment: The statement is not true. Consider $f(x)=x^2$ in the domain $[0,1]$. The minimum is at $x=0$, and the maximum is at $x=1$, but $f(x)$ is monotone.

Answer (score 1):

As several people have pointed out, this statement is false. The following statement is true: Let $I = (a,b)$ be an open interval, and suppose $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotone increasing and has a minimum $f(x_0) = m$ and a maximum $f(x_1) = M$. Then $f$ is identically $m$ on $(a,x_0)$ and identically $M$ on $(b,x_1)$. You can formulate an analogous statement for monotone decreasing functions by interchanging $x_0$ and $x_1$ in these two intervals on which $f$ is constant.

To prove this, just note that if $x \in (a,x_0)$, then monotone increasing implies $f(x) \leq f(x_0)$, but the fact that $x_0$ is a minimum implies $f(x) \geq f(x_0)$.

An implication of this statement phrased as your question title is that if a function which has a min and max on an open interval and is not constant on some "tail end" intervals cannot be monotone. As the comments have shown, these two additional hypotheses are both necessary. If the interval is not open, the min and max could occur at end points and the function need not be monotone in the middle. And if the min and max occur at tail ends, again the function need not be monotone in the middle.